# How to use an array in case?

Tags: php, arrays, case, switch-statement

How can I use an array in the case of a switch? This doesn't work and always take the default (3):

```
    switch ($my_array) {

        case array('george','paul'):
            $id     = 1;
            break;
        case array('paul','max'):
            $id     = 2;
            break;
        case array('eric'):
            $id     = 3;
            break;

        //default
        default:
            $id     = 3;
            break;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example should work, according to [the PHP manual on array operators](http://php.net/operators.array):

> `$a == $b`: TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.

Since [switch/case](http://php.net/switch) uses weak comparison, arrays are compared by using the `==` operator.

I've put a working example onto codepad: http://codepad.org/MhkGpPRp

Answer (score 0):

`switch()` statements are intended to match single conditions. I don't think there will be a way to use a switch for this. You need to use an `if else` chain instead:

```
if (in_array('george', $array) && in_array('paul', $array) && !in_array('max', $array)) {
  $id = 1;
}
else if(in_array('paul', $array) && in_array('max', $array)) {
 $id = 2;
}
else if (in_array('eric', $array)) {
  $id = 3;
}
else {
  $id = 3;
}
```

According to [array operator rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), you can use `==`, but the array members must be in the same order. Technically, it is only the keys and values that must match, but for a numeric-indexed array, this equates to the members being in the same numeric order.

```
if ($array == array('john', 'paul')) {
  $id = 1;
}
else if ($array == array('paul', 'max')) {
  $id = 2;    
}
else if ($array == array('eric')) {
  $id = 3;
}
else {
  $id = 3;
}
```

Comment: Ok, is this also possible?: if ($my_array==array('paul','max')){

Comment: @Jordy no, you cannot compare arrays with `==`.

Comment: @Jordy, wait I'm wrong - according to this you can http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: oh, very strange. Is your code the only solution to compare arrays?

Comment: @Jordy but array members must be in the same order for it to work.

Comment: Ok, so == is for the same array with the same values, and === is for the same array with the same values in the same order

Comment: @Jordy keys and values must be the same, so in effect for a numeric-indexed array they must also be in the same order `0=>john 1=>paul`

Answer (score 0):

PHP can switch on arrays, though you do need to have exactly the same keys of all the elements for the comparison to succeed. You might need to use [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to normalize the keys of $my_array. Otherwise it should work. `$my_array = array('paul','max');` should give $id=2.

Comment: I think that is not necessary. See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some like this:

```
switch (serialize($junctions)) {

    case serialize(array('george','paul')):
        $id     = 1;
        break;
    case serialize(array('paul','max')):
        $id     = 2;
        break;
    case serialize(array('eric')):
        $id     = 3;
        break;

    //default
    default:
        $id     = 3;
        break;

}
```

But you really want it?

Comment: many calls of serialize function scares me :) This one should be better [link](http://pastebin.com/4cXfkhsw) But see at @knittl answer  - if it works why invent something else?